# Create and apply a reusable chain of promises onto other promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, es6-promise, node-horseman

#### Context:

I'm using `node-horseman` to web scrape. The situation is that after each action i make the headless browser take, i generally want to see the results.

The results can be seen by running

```
horseman
    .open('http://www.google.com')
    .html()
    .then((html)=>{
        return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
            console.log(html);
            fs.writeFile("result.html", html)
            resolve();
       })
    })
    .screenshot("result.png")
    .close();
```

Which creates writes the html to `result.html` and writes a screenshot of the rendered page to `result.png`.

#### Question:

instead of copy pasting that string of 4 promises, is it possible to assign that string of promises to a variable or method and then apply it? E.g.,

```
horseman
    .open('http://www.google.com')
    .preview_result()
```

Where

```
function preview_result(){
    return html()
        .then((html)=>{
            return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
                console.log(html);
                fs.writeFile("result.html", html)
                resolve();
           })
        })
        .screenshot("test.png")
        .close();
}
```

or

```
var preview_result = 
    html()
    .then((html)=>{
        return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
            console.log(html);
            fs.writeFile("result.html", html)
            resolve();
       })
    })
    .screenshot("test.png")
    .close();
```

Comment: You can assign it to a variable or return it from a function, but no, it will still be a promise that may or may not have resolved.

Comment: `html()` seems to be a method of whatever `promiseUpToNow` is (so, not a promise, because promises don't have a `html` method) ... one problem with your two "alternatives" is the `html` function ... it's no longer a method on an object, so, what is it? and defining a function called `preview_result` doesn't magically add a method called `preview_result` to whatever `promiseUpToNow` object is - so, as shown, the code makes absolutely no sense at all

Comment: @JaromandaX That makes sense. I will update the code now to its full extent.

Comment: Should you need a `.then()` for your `.screenshot('test.png')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a reusable function in such a way that it takes a Promise as an input:

```
function previewResult(openedUrl){
  return openedUrl
    .html()
    .then((html)=>{
      return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        console.log(html);
        fs.writeFile("result.html", html, (error) => { // This way Promise will resolve only after the file was written
          if(error) {
            reject();
            return;
          }

          resolve();
        });
      })
    })
    .screenshot("test.png")
    .close();
}
```

This function will return something that was returned by `close()` function and if it was a Promise, you can simply continue a Promise chain.

You can use it this way:

```
const openedUrl = horseman.open('http://www.google.com');
previewResult(openedUrl)
  .then(() => { // Note that it will work only if close() returns a Promise
    console.log('all done!')
   });
```

Another approach is to use [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply):

```
function previewResult(){
  return this
    .html()
    .then((html)=>{
      return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        console.log(html);
        fs.writeFile("result.html", html, (error) => { // This way Promise will resolve only after the file was written
          if(error) {
            reject();
            return;
          }

          resolve();
        });
      })
    })
    .screenshot("test.png")
    .close();
}

const openedUrl = horseman.open('http://www.google.com');
previewResult.apply(openedUrl)
  .then(() => { // Note that it will work only if close() returns a Promise
    console.log('all done!')
   });
```

But I don't see any significant advantages in it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to do it with pure promises (which I will designate as the "accepted answer" when someone finds a solution) but...

`node-horseman` comes with the following functionality to create custom horseman promises

```
Horseman.registerAction('preview', function(results_path) {
  // The function will be called with the Horseman instance as this
  var self = this;
  // Return the horseman chain, or any Promise
  return this
    .html()
    .then((html)=>{
        return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
            console.log("html written");
            fs.writeFile(results_path+".html", html)
            resolve();
       })
    })
    .screenshot(results_path+".png")
});
```

Which results in the following doing as desired:

```
horseman
    .open('http://www.google.com')
    .preview()
    .close()
```

reference: https://github.com/johntitus/node-horseman

Their documentation rocks.